# how to test ActivityCompat.requestPermission on android M?

Tags: android

here is my java code.

```
public static void checkSinglePermissionCompat(final Activity activity,
                                               ActionNeedsPermission action, final String permission,
                                               final int permissionCode, String message) {
    int hasPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
    if (hasPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        action.performAction();
    } else {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
            showRationaleDialog(activity, message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, permissionCode);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, permissionCode);
        }
    }
}
```

my gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion "android-MNC"
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion "MNC"
    targetSdkVersion "MNC"
}
}
```

and my manifest file

```
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

it just callback permission denied, did not show the system permission request dialog. anyone could help me? thx

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample [Google sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/)

```
 <!-- Note that all required permissions are declared here in the Android manifest.
 On Android M and above, use of these permissions is only requested at run time. -->
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>**

<!-- The following permissions are only requested if the device is on M or above.
 On older platforms these permissions are not requested and will not be available. -->
**<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />**
```